# Change Google Account in Jelly Beam 4.1.2

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-account

My bro had a phone and he doesn't remember the password, I need to change the account of that phone, it has **Android 4.1.2**, with a factory reset and data wipe would be enough to remove the current account? If not, what are the steps to follow?

Comment: @beeshyams the duplicate you suggested is about gmail app, what I want is to change the phones account, kinda different right?

Comment: @beeshyams Then what do I need to do? My bro's account is there and he doesn't remember the passoword.

Comment: See under settings, accounts, and remove Google account. I am not sure of the exact place this setting is available

Comment: It asks for the password @beeshyams

Comment: Since that is not available, looks like no option but to try factory reset

Comment: Side-note: As it's Android < 5.x, a factory-reset should be sufficient. Careful with Android 5 and up, as "factory reset protection" (FRP) might kick in. Worth a look in this context: our [locked-out tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info).